# Python's PIL: using fromarray() and display numpy array with colormap

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, tkinter-canvas

I have a numpy array of `dtype=np.int32` which contains values in range of 0-255 only.

I've successfully managed to display it inside tkinter's canvas widget like that:

```
def set(self, image):
    self.canvas.delete("all")
    img = Image.fromarray(image, "I").resize((
        self.width, self.height)).convert("RGB")
    self.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
    self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=self.img, anchor="nw")
```

However I still get grayscaled image.
First I want it to just display with colors, later I'd like to use a familiar colormap like jet. I do have a dictionary contain the jet values, how can I integrate everything?

Comment: values `0-255`  may give you only greyscale RGB (0,0,0), (1,1,1) ... (254,254,254), (255,255,255)

Comment: But can't this be used with a colormap dictionary?

Comment: hi @galah92, did you figure out how to do this?

Comment: @nababs can't really remember and I don't have access to the code, sorry.